# Getting 400 error in Laravel for localhost server

Tags: php, laravel

This is my .env file. I am trying to run the Laravel project in the localhost server but I am getting 500 errors for my all assets and the is no error in the log file.

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:1vaU3dfc+sWjx45ghgh46zginRsEa2dp2SBL+Ujs6QCb5c=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_MODE=demo
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000

LOG_CHANNEL=single

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=6v_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379


MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Still I am getting error of 400 for assets.[image]

Comment: please check your php version first

Comment: `APP_URL=http://27.0.0.1:8000` this is a typo right? Also all those are 404 errors, not 500 errors, meaning the files are not found.

Comment: Yeah. sorry for the mistake. @apokryfos

Comment: php version is: PHP 7.4.21 (cli) (built: Jul 13 2021 03:14:47) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.21, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have an assets folder under public folder and the required css and js files. As I see in your given image it says the assets not exist in the given path and giving you 404 Not Found Exception.

```
{{ asset('assets/front-end/js/theme.min.js') }}
```

You can call asset like above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to exclude the 'public' folder from the url when loading these files via the web browser. Consider using the `asset()` method. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset to generate the url.

Also make sure you have set the public folder rather than the base folder as the root at the web server level.